# How to draw a circle when a button is clicked in android?

Tags: android, geometry

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<Button
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/go"
android:text="go"
/>
```

I want to add a circle below the button in the linear layout.How do i do it?What changes need to be done to the main.xml?

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {
 private Button checkButton;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
        start();
        }

        private void start() {
            checkButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.go);
            checkButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                        }
                    });
}
```

What needs to be filled in the onClick method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make bitmap then draw on its canvas then add this bitmap to an imageview for example.

Create A bitmap:

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100,  Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

Canvas c = new Canvas(bmp);
c.drawCircle(60,50,25, paint);
```

setting to imageview

```
img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: Thank u.but What must be the value of config? @Marko Niciforovic

Comment: I edited my answer, now you have all values. You can modify paint(color) of circle and rest of values as you want obviously.

Comment: try to put this as config = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 and use setImageBitmap better

Comment: Thanks.it is working.But how do i add one more circle to the image view just below this circle?

Comment: the same way you added this one?